# scanf a big hexadecimal value

Tags: c, hex, scanf

I have a issue trying to use scanf to get a big hexadecimal num (12 chars) from the user.

it seems to only get the last 8 chars, eg - ABFFFFFFFF will become 0000FFFFFFFF.

this is my code -

```
unsigned long long address;
scanf("%x",&address);
printf("Address: %#014x", address);
```

for this input: "ABFFFFFFFF"  the output would be:

> Address: 0x0000ffffffff

i have tried playing a bit with the scanf format, but to no avail.

Comment: Depending on the compiler and platform you usually need a different format specifier for `long long` values, i.e. different from `"%x"`.

Comment: @dlask: the format specifier does not depend on the compiler nor platform, it is `"%llx"`.  The actual size of the `unsigned long long` type depends on the platform/compiler, but it is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits, enough for `ABFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @chqrlie You are right. I had a doubt about old Microsoft compilers, but the `"%llx"` seems to be supported at least from VC++ 2008.

Comment: @dlask: For compatibility with older compilers, the rule of thumb is simple: if `long long` is supported, `%lld` is supported too, if `long long` is not available, use `long` and `%ld`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use "%llx" for both scanf format and printf. See the manual page for additional details.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm, still not very familiar with c.